# AWS Amplfy withAuthenticator hide "Sign up" option

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

is it possible to hide the sign up tab on the amplify ui?

I am using the HOC components withAuthenticator on my app but I want to be able to hide the sign up option!

my app.

```
export default withAuthenticator(App)
```

is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this:

```
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'

function App() {
   return <div>My app or react-router-dom or something else</div>
}

export default withAuthenticator(App, { hideSignUp: true })
```

That remove the button "create account".